# ¿Por qué decimos "bisiesto" y no "bisexto" si viene de "sextus" igual que "sexto"?

Tags: etimología, tiempo, números, latín

Un [*año bisiesto*](https://dle.rae.es/a%C3%B1o#MY7vhBG) es ese *año que tiene un día más que el común, añadido al mes de febrero*. Un poco más ampliamente, la wikipedia lo define como:

> Año bisiesto es una expresión que deriva del latín *bis sextus dies ante calendas martii* (repítase el sexto día antes del primer día del mes de marzo), que correspondía a un día extra intercalado entre el 23 y el 24 de febrero por Julio César.

Mirando la etimología de bisiesto vemos efectivamente que tiene que ver con el sexto día:

> [**bisiesto**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=bisiesto)
>   `Del lat. bisextus.`
>
> 1. m. año bisiesto.

Mirando *sexto* observamos efectivamente que volvemos a toparnos con el *sextus* de marras:

> [**sexto, ta**](https://dle.rae.es/sexto?m=form)
>   `Del lat. sextus.`

Sin embargo, la palabra *bis sextus* se convirtió en *bisiesto* y no *bisexto* como parecería lógico. ¿Es posible saber por qué?

Comment: FYI in Portuguese, "bissexto" and "sexto" kept the same ending

Comment: ¡Qué interesante, @Alan! ¿Y cómo se dice _siesta_? Wordreference dice que [_sesta_](https://www.wordreference.com/espt/siesta), por lo que sería un caso también de evolución etimológica diferente según la palabra.

Comment: WR está correcto y estoy de acuerdo contigo sobre la evolución etimológica distinta.

Comment: En portugués no hubo diptongación de las vocales laxas latinas, así que la diferencia sería sólo del tratamiento de la *x*. Por lo que estoy leyendo en port. moderno *x* se pronuncia /s/ en esta posición pero eleva la vocal: *sesta* /sɛstɐ/ vs. *sexta* /sestɐ/, para empezar (después pasan otras cosas según el dialecto en cuestión). Obrigado, @AlanEvangelista!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nunca es fácil responder una pregunta de "¿por qué?" referida a la etimología, porque las palabras evolucionan a veces de formas caprichosas. En el caso de *sexto* vs. *bisiesto* la diferencia es clara: la primera es una forma culta, adoptada directamente del latín "salteándose" la evolución fonética normal del romance, mientras que la segunda es una forma vernácula con una evolución regular: diptongación de la *e* laxa (antes *e* corta) en sílaba acentuada, y simplificación de /ks/ en /s/ en final de sílaba.

Por qué siguieron estas rutas diferentes es imposible de responder. Resulta un poco raro porque normalmente las palabras cultas son las menos frecuentes, pero *bisiesto* es y seguramente siempre fue una palabra mucho menos frecuente que *sexto*. Que esta evolución divergente podía ocurrir en este caso particular queda probado por un doblete exacto: *siesta* vs. *sexta*, donde *siesta* deriva del latín *sexta (hora)*. Chequeando en el CORDE hay una instancia de *siesto* como ordinal en un texto de 1494 que hace una lista de ríos (citando algunos ordinales como palabras y otras como números romanos):

> ... primero, que aparta los judios de los arabios, de los quales los
>   unos creyen en Dios & los otros adoran los idolos. El ii. es que se
>   abrio maravillosamente ante los hijos de Israel (...) El
>   **siesto** es que la agua suya fue santificada tocando la muy santa carne de nuestro Redemptor quando ende fue babtizado & ordenado el
>   santo sacramento de babtismo por el cual nos somos salvos, como es
>   escripto en el .ii. capitulo de Sant Lucas. El septimo es que dende
>   vio Sant Juan Babtista (...)

Hay también muchos ejemplos de *sesto*, que es una simplificación fonética sobre *sexto*, seguramente posterior al lapso en que se diptongaron las vocales laxas del latín vulgar. Con esto y la persistencia de la palabra *siesta* basta para establecer que la evolución normal del latín de hecho se produjo, pero quedó anulada más tarde en el caso del ordinal. Pienso que quizá el ordinal, aunque se use muy seguido, debía aparecer especialmente en escritos legales y académicos, donde habría tendencia a restaurar las formas latinas, mientras que *bisiesto* no sufrió esa presión (y desde luego tampoco *siesta*, institución popular si las hay).

Comment: ¡Qué grande! En los comentarios Alan nos descubrió que en el portugués pasó algo parecido, pero no igual: usan _bissexto_, pero dicen _sesta_.

Comment: @fedorqui Acabo de verlo y me sorprende; cuando se enseña portugués a hablantes de castellano no se le presta la atención debida a los pares contrastantes de las vocales medias, y yo hubiera creído que *sesta* y *sexta* se pronunciaban iguales.